# PHP Regex rewrite .something to .php

Tags: php, regex

I have this php script:

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['p'])) {
    $allowedPages = array();
    $openDir = opendir('./pages/');

    while(false !== ($entry = readdir($openDir))) {
        $allowedPages[] = $entry;
    }

    closedir($openDir);

    preg_replace('~\..*~', '.php', $_GET['p']);

    echo $_GET['p'];
    if(in_array($_GET['p'], $allowedPages)) {
        include './pages/'.$_GET['p'];
    } else {
        echo '404';
    }
}
?>
```

What I want is, if you go to mysite.com/?p=test.html, test.html should rewrite to test.php but its not working.

It works on RegExr: http://regexr.com?387t0

How to fix?

UPDATE:

How to rewrite index to index.php?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer also to your second part:

```
preg_replace('/([^.]+)(?:\.[^.]+)?$/', "$1.php", $string);
```